# How to save multiple checkbox values to string before create?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, checkbox

in view

```
<input id="checkbox-1"  type="checkbox" value="drama" name="user[book][]">    
<input id="checkbox-2"  type="checkbox" value="poem" name="user[book][]">    
<input id="checkbox-3" type="checkbox" value="fantasy" name="user[book][]">
```

if checked 1 and 3 checkbox, it is expected that something like "drama, fantasy" save in field book

in controller

```
private
 def user_params
  params[:user][:book] = params[:user][:book].join(',') 
  params.require(:user).permit(title, email, :book, message)
 end 




def create        
   @user = User.new(user_params)        
   if @user.save        
      UserMailer.new_feedback(@user).deliver        
      render :json => { :result => 'Text message' }        
  end    
end
```

When I try to save the form input to database i get the following error:

```
Template is missing
```

Without `params[:user][:book] = params[:user][:book].join(',')` works fine, but I need convert array to string for storing in column DB

Comment: Paste the `params` variable.

Comment: show action where you save this. I think you lack `redirect_to`

Answer (score 0):

If I have understand you have code

```
def create
  @user = User.new user_params
  if @user.save
     UserMailer.new_feedback(@user).deliver
     render :json => {:result => 'Text message'}
  end
# what happens if doesnt pass
end
```

You need

```
def create
  @user = User.new user_params
  if @user.save
     UserMailer.new_feedback(@user).deliver
     render :json => {:result => 'Text message'}
  else
     render :json => @user.errors.first, :status => 400
     # when user does not create controller is looking for some template and you don't have template
  end      
end
```